# How to schedule a transaction to a Contract?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, quorum, scheduling

I have a simple getter-setter contract. I want to schedule transactions for a method of my contract on a particular date and time.

Do we have a function to schedule transactions to a contract in Quorum Blockchain? Please help me with it.

Comment: That Question is for How to schedule a normal Transaction. My question is How to schedule a transaction to a contract. For a contract interaction, we call multiple methods and also pass parameter values(if required)

Comment: There is no such thing as "normal" and "not normal" transaction. Ismael gave you the correct direction.